# MySQL date format functions in Drupal

Tags: database

How can I do a MySQL date function in Drupal?
I have this now:

```
$select = db_select('someTable', 'st');
$select->addExpression('DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(created), "%Y-%m")', 'createdMonth');

$date = $select->execute()->fetchAll();
```

When I run this I get an exception that says:

```
"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '%Y-%m' in 'field list'"
```

But if I print the $select object I see it should run

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(created), "%Y-%m") AS createdMonth FROM {someTable} st
```

And when I copy this to Sequel Pro it just runs.

What am I missing?

Comment: Take a look on this it may helps you http://cgit.drupalcode.org/month/commit/?id=a8b28ea

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're a 'victim' of MySQL's [`ANSI_QUOTES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes) SQL mode:

> Treat “"” as an identifier quote character (like the “`” quote character) and not as a string quote character. You can still use “`” to quote identifiers with this mode enabled. **With ANSI_QUOTES enabled, you cannot use double quotation marks to quote literal strings, because it is interpreted as an identifier.**

Emphasis mine.

That explains why MySQL is trying to find a column called `'%y-%m'` rather than interpreting it as a string.

So you need to switch your SQL mode to something else, or (more reasonably), just use single quotes for literals:

```
$select->addExpression("DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(created), '%Y-%m')", 'createdMonth');
```

Many other DBMSs don't accept double quotes for string literals, so using single quotes is a good habit to get into anyway.

Comment: I think the Drupal coding standards suggest to use the double quotes for SQL strings exactly to avoid this problem. It has been a while since I was approving the CVS applications to become maintainer, so the coding standards could be changed, in the while. `:D`